# Map Stored Procedure Result without Columns to a Model

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns two columns without specifying their name, one is the ID (int) and the other one is a string. It is not possible for me to alter the stored procedure so that it can return the results with column names

If I let Visual Studio to create the `.edmx` file with the stored procedures in the  `dbContext`, it creates a new model class with two properties called `Column1` and `Column2`. The problem is that when I run it, I receive the following error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Schema.addCliente_Result'. A member of the type, 'Column1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Is there any other way to map the result to maybe a a `dictionary<int,string>` or anything else  that does not need the column name?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `KeyValuePair`. It saves the value specified for your key. You can create list of `KeyValuePair` if you have more pairs and you want to iterate through it easier. I'm not sure if this helps in your case, sorry if it's not helping.

[KeyValuePair MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may want to consider projection since you don't want it mapped to a Model. Projection is when the result of a query is output to a different type than the one queried. Either way, you can use the results of the stored procedure to either create an anonymous type or a class of your own. Since there's no code for me to reference, I have an example as follows:

Class used to store results

```
public Class Result
{
    public int myID {get; set;}
    public string myString {get; set;}
}
```

Code to call stored procedure

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyDatabase"];
var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
string query = @"my_stored_procedure";
using (var sqlAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
{
    sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // Ex: Parameters if your sp takes one
    var dataDate = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@DataDate", Value = DateTime.Now };
    sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(dataDate);
    var results = new DataSet();
    sqlAdpt.Fill(results);
    List<Result> resultList = results.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().
        Select(dataRow => new Result
        {
            myID = dataRow.Field<int>("ID"),
            myString = dataRow.Field<string>("column_I_cant_change")
        }).ToList();

}
```